# Cannot drop anonymous user from mysql.user

Tags: mysql

I am trying to DROP the anonymous users from my mysql.users database. However, I have been getting odd behavior. When I enter the command:

```
DROP User ''@'WOPR';
```

I was getting a generic error message. So, I rebooted my machine, and tried it again. This time I got the response

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected.
```

But when I put in

`SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';`

The return is:

```
+------+------+----------+
| User | Host | Password |
+------+------+----------+
|      | WOPR |          |
+------+------+----------+
```

(WOPR is my hostname)

I run the command

`DROP User ''@'WOPR';`

and get the same result.

I am running a fresh install of MySQL 5.5 on Arch Linux, kernel version 2.6.33.

Does anyone know what can cause this behavior?

Comment: Please get the word out to send questions of this nature to the DBA StackExchange !!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='' AND host='WOPR';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This should do it for you.

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

MySQL has certain users preinstalled into mysql.user. Also, mysql.db comes with two users that have anonymous access and full privileges to test databases.

Just do this

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db \G
```

and you will see that anyone that connects to test or any database starting with test_ can pretty much do everything in the test database. This is bad since a person with full access to any test database can eat up a disk in matter of minutes.

Example:

```
use test
CREATE TABLE junk (INT a) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO junk VALUES (1);
```

OK, big deal. It makes a table with 4 bytes.

Now trying running this SQL statement 30 times:

```
INSERT INTO junk SELECT * FROM junk;
```

Hey an instant table with 1,073,741,824 rows (4GB+ file) !!! Imaging having full rights to a test database where you can wreak this kind of havoc on a disk.

My advice to you is to run this to clean out test user access:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE db LIKE 'tes%' AND user='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

For further clarification, see my post [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db)

Cheers !!!

Comment: Hi Rolando,
That did the trick, thanks! I am actually fixing my test database access right now.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use the `drop user` syntax instead of modifying the underlying `mysql.user` table directly?

Comment: @Pacerier Please look at the original question. The real problem is that the `DROP USER` syntax does not work when the user field is blank (empty string). You must do it the way answer specifies.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, Are there other solutions besides hacking around with the `mysql.user` table?

Comment: @Pacerier If you read my last link, you will realize that MySQL (now Oracle) places two rows directly into `mysql.db` upon installation that will allow anonymous users to access a test database. Interestingly, I was told that Percona Server's installation deletes those rows before its installation is complete (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66584/only-grant-usage-but-can-still-select-drop-create/66590#comment120842_66590). Since you are using MySQL, either run mysql_secure_installation or delete those two rows yourself.