# Only "grant usage", but can still select, drop, create?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a mysql user (I'll call) "user5" who only has "grant usage" (i.e. no privileges) in the output of "show grants", but can still do a select on database "app_db" (which is what I want, but I do understand how it has that privilege).  There is no anonymous user.  How can user5 be using its database with this configuration?

When logged in as user5:

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user5@10.14.%                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user5'@'10.14.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*long hash' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When logged in as root, looking at the User table:

```
mysql> select User, Host, Select_priv from mysql.user;
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| User     | Host          | Select_priv |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| root     | localhost     | Y           |
| root     | 127.0.0.1     | Y           |
| root     | 10.14.12.8    | Y           |
| user5    | 10.14.%       | N           |
| (other named non-root users)           |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

...yet, as user5, "select * from app_db.users" returns results.

Comment: Any entries in `mysql.db` for the user?

Comment: @Derek Downey What is mysql.db?  Oh, I think you mean the mysql database.  Yes, per above, it shows use in mysql.user with no privileges.

Comment: @DerekDowney I was just thinking the same thing

Comment: Hey Paul, please login as root and run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`. After that, find out if user5 can still do things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, your user5 has database (i.e. schema) privileges, just not server-wide privileges.  So look here.

```
USE app_db;
SHOW GRANTS FOR user5;
```

or check in the data dictionary for the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES
WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '%user5%';
```

if not anything, then maybe also check

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '%user5%';
```

Comment: After "use app_db", "show grants" returns the same entry as before (just "grant usage").  The two selects above both return the empty set.

Comment: How about the 2nd query above, the one on SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES view.  Does that shed any light on user5?  Or mabye run that query without the where clause, i.e.: `SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` just to see all the DB-level privileges.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I was just trying to edit my comment.  There were SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES were there under a more fully qualified IP (i.e. not 10.14.%, but 10.14.12.%).  Confusing, but that explains it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When I see GRANT USAGE for a specific user, that user can connect, get global status variables, and that's it. ***There is one horrible exception: THE TEST DATABASE !!!***

Did you know that there are two entries in the `mysql.db` tables that allow anonymous logins to authenticate when the database is named test or a database whose first five characters are `test_` ?

I wrote about this a long time ago :

My Posted Question : [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db)

My Posted Answer : [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db/13363#13363)

This is still a chronic problem to this very day.

To check this out, please run

```
select db,user,host from mysql.db where LEFT(db,4)='test';
```

If your output is the following:

```
mysql> select db,user,host from mysql.db where LEFT(db,4)='test';
+---------+------+------+
| db      | user | host |
+---------+------+------+
| test    |      | %    |
| test\_% |      | %    |
+---------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

and you are putting tables in a test database, then this is the root cause.

Comment: FWIW, this is fixed in Percona Server. I.e. we just don't add those rows in our distribution.